# How to make a MATLAB function to be run in html?

Tags: c++, html, matlab, matlab-deployment

I've developed a MATLAB code that I think it is useful to be used by researchers. How can I embed it in a website to be used free?

It gets two integers and return a set of integers

Also it is possible to convert it to `c++`, If it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956000/running-matlab-code-from-php

Comment: It didn't help me. Actually I'm only familiar with `Microsoft Office Front Page`. Is it possible using that? Thanks

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: that post lists some of the easiest ways to deploy MATLAB solutions. Your other option is to just rewrite your code into a Javascript web app, or some other language with proper support for web frameworks (C#, Java, PHP, Python, Ruby, ..)

Answer (score 1):

Submit your m-file(s) to [Matlab Central File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/), this is the perfect place for it.

Comment: I didn't mean to simply copy the code! I want to put it in html where it could be run by all visitors.